# Echo all row's into table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So i have a database with 33 column's 
Now this is my query :

```
    $q3 = "SELECT * FROM qbd";
$r3 = $db1->query($q3);
while ($result = $r3->fetchAll()){
    foreach($result as $row3){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td colspan='2'>Kill ".$row3['ID']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row3['Dragon_Bones']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row3['Royal_Dragonhide']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    } 

}
```

How can i make it so that i only need to have 1 `$row3` and not need to write all the column names in it?

Comment: I am not PHP guy, but as an IDEA I will suggest that. Inside Foreach Loop, in a row you will get array of columns, you can go through that array using one more foreach loop.

Comment: There are ways of working around this - but it's a bad idea - it compromises the understandability of the code and can lead to unplanned side-efects. BTW Using 'fetchAll' without a LIMIT in the query is also a bad idea

Comment: It's not improving readability of your code but you can do it like AK47 mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `fetch()` and fetch associate instead of `fetchAll`. Try this.

```
while ($result = $r3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

  echo '<tr>';

  foreach($result as $value){

     echo '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
   }
   echo '</tr>';

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a second foreach to traverse to array you get as follows:

```
while ($result = $r3->fetchAll())
{
    foreach($result as $row3)
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach($row3 as $key=>$val)
        {
            echo $key;
            echo $val;
        }
        echo "</tr>";        
    } 

}
```

This will display the key (column name) and the value in it.

If you want to just display the values, you can use this instead:

```
while ($result = $r3->fetchAll())
{
    foreach($result as $row3)
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach($row3 as $key=>$val)
        {
            echo $val;
        }
        echo "</tr>";        
    } 

}
```

Comment: Well, this will work but it's printing the column-name for every row - just to have this in mind

Comment: Tested it but all results are double printed,

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to put out a table of the rows, and want the headings on the first row then you can use mysqli_data_seek() to reset the pointer back to the start after processing the first row to get the titles.

Something like this (assuming you can use mysqli_fetch_assoc):-

```
<?php

$q3 = "SELECT * FROM qbd";
$r3 = $db1->query($q3);
if ($result = $r3->fetch_assoc())
{
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($result as $row3_key=>$row3_value)
    {
        echo "<td>".$row3_key."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    $db1->data_seek(0);
    while ($result = $r3->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach($result as $row3_key=>$row3_value)
        {
            echo "<td>".$row3_value."</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
} 

?>
```

EDIT - if your db class doesn't support mysqli_data_seek() (or if you are using an unbuffered query):-

```
<?php

$q3 = "SELECT * FROM qbd";
$r3 = $db1->query($q3);
if ($result = $r3->fetch_assoc())
{
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($result as $row3_key=>$row3_value)
    {
        echo "<td>".$row3_key."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    OutputRow($result);
    while ($result = $r3->fetch_assoc())
    {
        OutputRow($result);
    }
} 

function OutputRow($result)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($result as $row3_key=>$row3_value)
    {
        echo "<td>".$row3_value."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}

?>
```

Comment: The idea should work, but without knowing more about your system I can't debug (ie, what methods does the database class you are using support?).

Answer (score 0):

```
$keys = array();
$values = array();

echo '<table>';

while ($result = $r3->fetchAll()){
    foreach($result as $row3){

        foreach($row3 as $key=>$val){
            for($i=1;$i=30;$i++){
                $keys[]=$key;
            }
            $values[] = $val;       
        }   
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach($keys as $k){
            echo $k;
        }            
        foreach($values as $v){
            echo $v;
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    } 
}

echo '</table>'
```